# Python: delay of exit()

Tags: python

File in exe. Here my code:

```
 import time
number = 777
run = True

while run:
    guess = int(input('For your luck buddy: '))

    if guess == number:
        print('Well done! Leprecon bless ya.')
        run = False
    elif guess < number:
        print('Big no')
    else:
        print('Miss')
else:
    exit(0)
    if exit:
        time.sleep(3)
```

What's wrong with my code? How can i delay the function exit() after printing right number? File in exe.

Comment: Why not just `time.sleep(3); exit(0)`? You are exiting before delaying...

Comment: Please be aware, that [`exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html?highlight=exit#constants-added-by-the-site-module) should not be used in programs.

Comment: There are cases where exit is relevant to use, when working with UIs @Matthias

Comment: @oskros I was just citing the documentation and I never had to use `exit` while working with UIs. What I did use was [`sys.exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit) with programs running in the console.

Comment: @Matthias my bad, I was confusing it with `sys.exit` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, there is  no need for the `run` flag, it basically emulates a `break` statement.
The `else` statement in the end of the `while` loop is also unnecessary.
If you want to wait 3 seconds before `exit()` then you simply place the `sleep` statement before the `exit` statement.
Also as Matthias pointed out in the comments you shouldn't call `exit` manually, when the interpreter reaches the end of your program / function, the execution will end anyway.

```
import time
number = 777

while True:
    guess = int(input('For your luck buddy: '))

    if guess == number:
        print('Well done! Leprecon bless ya.')
        break
    elif guess < number:
        print('Big no')
    else:
        print('Miss')
        
time.sleep(3)
```